# Should I meet with a chiropractor just for yearly "maintenance"?

Tags: bones, musculoskeletal-system, massage, masseuse, chiropractor

Or are chiropractors just for special case problems?

I'm asking because my health insurance lets me pick from several benefits and chiropractic operations are part of the benefits I'm considering.

Comment: Anyone who thinks you need periodic "maintenance" of a physical condition should be able to explain exactly how it will help you, what your expectations should be, and what the alternatives are.